# How to add attachment to Microsoft Graph based email

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, office365, httpclient, microsoft-graph-mail

This is my code to send an email in Graph.
Without the attachment part it works great.
With, I get an error: Badrequest.
I have to clue how to fix it. I can't find any examples on internet.
thanks
Frank

```
var emailMessage = new
    {
        message = new
        {
            subject = messageSubject,
            body = new
            {
                contentType = "Text",
                content = messageBody
            },
            toRecipients = new[]
            {
                        new
                        {
                            emailAddress = new
                            {
                                address = userEmail
                            }
                        }
            },
            Attachments = new List<Attachment>
                {
                    new Attachment
                    {
                        OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                        Name = "TextFile1.txt",
                        ContentType = "text/plain",

                    },
                },
        }
};

// Convert the email message to a JSON string and send the email via Microsoft Graph
var jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailMessage);
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{graphApiEndpoint}/users/{userEmail}/sendMail", new StringContent(jsonMessage, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to send email. Status code: " + response.StatusCode);
    }
```

> Attachment is actually, Microsoft.Graph.Models.Attachment
> Attachment does not contain a
> definition for ContenBytes. I've tried:

```
Attachment = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Attachment
                        {
                            OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                            Name = "TextFile1.txt",
                            ContentType = "text/plain",
                            AdditionalData =new Dictionary<string,object>
                            {
                                { "contentBytes", contentBytes }}},
```

Answer (score 1):

The new Kioata based SDK uses System.Text.Json rather than Newtonsoft's and it its Classes (eg Microsoft.Graph.Models.Attachment) have their own custom serializers.

So the easiest way to serialize one of the Graph SDK classes is just use the Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Json implementation eg

```
        var draftMessage = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message
        {
            Subject = "draft Messages",
        };
        draftMessage.ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>() { new Recipient() { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress() { Address = recipient } } };
        byte[] littleStream = File.ReadAllBytes(littleAttachment.FullName);
        draftMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>
        {
            new FileAttachment
            {
                Name = "TextFile1.txt",
                ContentType = "text/plain",
                ContentBytes = littleStream
            }
        };
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip,
            AllowTrailingCommas = true,
        };
        var jsonSerializerWriter = new Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializationWriter();
        jsonSerializerWriter.WriteObjectValue(string.Empty, draftMessage);
        var serializedStream = jsonSerializerWriter.GetSerializedContent();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(serializedStream);
        string jsonMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

You can use also use the base class for attachment like

```
        draftMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>
        {
            new Attachment
            {
                OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                Name = littleAttachment.Name,
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {
                        "contentBytes", Convert.ToBase64String(littleStream)
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

but it's cleaner and more readable to use FileAttachment

The unit tests for SDK also demonstrate this https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Test/Models/ModelSerializationTests.cs

If you use the GraphServiceClient from the SDK you wouldn't have to worry about any of this.

Comment: Thanks Glen but I can't get it to work.
Bad request is the message I get back.

Comment: Can you post the JSON it produces?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing `contentBytes` in the [attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fileattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) which must be the base64-encoded contents of the file.

Try something like this

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"path\to\TextFile1.txt");
var contentBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

var emailMessage = new
    {
        message = new
        {
            subject = messageSubject,
            body = new
            {
                contentType = "Text",
                content = messageBody
            },
            toRecipients = new[]
            {
                        new
                        {
                            emailAddress = new
                            {
                                address = userEmail
                            }
                        }
            },
            Attachments = new List<Attachment>
                {
                    new Attachment
                    {
                        OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                        Name = "TextFile1.txt",
                        ContentType = "text/plain",
                        ContentBytes = contentBytes
                    },
                },
        }
};
```

If `Attachment` is your class then add a new property `string ContentBytes`.

File size should be under 3 MB. If you are attaching larger file you need to create [an upload session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http).